# javascript issue in jsf/icefaces

Tags: javascript, jsf

jsf command button doesn't invoking javascript , please suggestions

```
<ice:commandButton id="submit" onclick="validationmessage();" value="Submit"
```

Comment: Stop openning accounts. For every question, you just open an account and you never accept the answers. Consider registering your user account. Now you've a lot of questions with unaccepted answers spread out over different accounts. stackoverflow.com/users/293339, stackoverflow.com/users/388720, stackoverflow.com/users/388945, stackoverflow.com/users/392116, stackoverflow.com/users/418228, stackoverflow.com/users/383890, stackoverflow.com/users/437700, stackoverflow.com/users/436514, stackoverflow.com/users/415565 and stackoverflow.com/users/412351

Answer (score 0):

1. Check page source. Does validationmessage() function exist in it?
2. Check if onclick works. Put something like "alert('blabla')" there. Does it work?